# Maximum number of servers that can connect to a san?

Tags: storage-area-network

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Maximum number of servers that can connect to a san ?](https://serverfault.com/questions/236195/maximum-number-of-servers-that-can-connect-to-a-san)

Maximum number of servers that can connect to a san ?

Comment: This is a programmer forum, so the answer is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that a SAN in general would have a theoretical maximum number of servers that can access it. There will be practical limits, but these will depend on your model of SAN and also how the network or Fibre Channel fabrics are set up.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say around the maximum number of hosts addressable using the network numbering scheme in use. For IPv4, that comes out to right around 4 billion.

Of course, you might not *want* to connect that many hosts to a single SAN, even if you have them.